# Conditional where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I want to apply the conditional where clause That is if my `barcode` parameter comes null then i want to fetch all the records and if it comes with value then i want to fetch only matching records for the second part i am able to fetch the matching records but i am stuck at fetching the all records in case of null value i have tried as below ,

```
 SELECT item 
 FROM tempTable
 WHERE 
  ((ISNULL(@barcode,0)=1)
      // but this is not fetching all the records if barcode is null 
   OR
   ISNULL(@barcode,0!= 1 AND tempTable.barcode LIKE @barcode+'%'))
      //THis is working perfect
```

so any help will be great

Comment: `ISNULL(@barcode,0!= 1` looks like a missing parenthesis

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I might have misunderstood what you ask, but the logic [OR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188361.aspx) operator might help:

```
SELECT item 
 FROM tempTable
 WHERE 
 @barcode IS NULL OR tempTable.barcode LIKE @barcode+'%'
```

If `@barcode` is `NULL`, it returns all the records, and when it is not `NULL`, it returns all of the records that fulfill the condition `LIKE @barcode+'%'`

**Important**

Also, bear in mind that using the [OR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188361.aspx) operator can seemingly cause funny results when used with several complex conditions AND-ed together, and not enclosed properly in braces:

```
<A> AND <B> AND <C> OR <D> AND <E> AND <F>
```

Should most likely actually be formulated as:

```
(<A> AND <B> AND <C>) OR (<D> AND <E> AND <F>)
```

Remember, the parser does not know what you want to achieve, you have to describe your intents properly...

Answer (score 2):

I think you could simplify it to:

```
  SELECT item 
 FROM tempTable
 WHERE @barcode IS NULL OR tempTable.barcode LIKE @barcode+'%'
```

so when @barcode is null you'll get everything - i.e. the Like part of the where won't need to execute.  If @barcode has a value then the Like will be executed.

Comment: if the value can be 0 or null and you want everything for these cases, just change the where to WHERE isnull(@barcode,0) = 0 OR tempTable.barcode LIKE @barcode+'%'

Answer (score 2):

If the barcode field is non-null, then this is the method I would use -

```
SELECT item 
FROM tempTable
WHERE barcode like isnull(@barcode, barcode) + '%'
```

If @barcode is null all records are returned and if it is non null then only matching records are returned.

If the barcode field is nullable then -

```
SELECT item 
FROM tempTable
WHERE isnull(barcode, '') like isnull(@barcode, isnull(barcode, '')) + '%'
```

Same as the first but here we convert the null values in the barcode field to blank strings before doing the compare.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate answer and an attempt at the bounty

```
declare @barcode nvarchar(10) -- chose nvarchar not necessarily should be nvarchar
select @barcode= NULL
--select @barcode='XYZ'
if @barcode is null
select item from temptable;
else
select item from temptable where temptable.barcode like @barcode+'%';
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have to do this, I would have done like

```
SELECT item 
 FROM tempTable
 WHERE 
( ( ISNULL(@barcode,'') <> '')  AND ( tempTable.barcode LIKE @barcode+'%' ) )
```

`( ISNULL(@barcode,'') <> '')` would also check if the variable is blank then it should not return anything. But if you just check for null, then in case when the `@barcode` is blank, you will be getting all `item` selected from the `tempTable`.

Answer (score 0):

If column `barcode` would be non-nullable, you could greatly simplify the query.
This is based on the fact that the pattern `'%'` matches *any* string; even an empty (i.e. zero-length) string.
Consequently, the following WHERE clause matches *all* records:

```
WHERE barcode LIKE '%'
```

You may notice that this has a very close resemblance to the WHERE clause you are using to filter records on a specific barcode:

```
WHERE barcode LIKE @barcode + '%'
```

In fact, they are so similar that we may as well use a single WHERE clause for both cases; after all, `'' + '%'` equals `'%'`!

```
IF @barcode IS NULL SET @barcode = ''
SELECT item FROM tempTable WHERE barcode LIKE @barcode + '%'
```

There is an even shorter version, which preserves the original value of `@barcode`:

```
SELECT item FROM tempTable WHERE barcode LIKE ISNULL(@barcode, '') + '%'
```

As mentioned earlier, this works only if column `barcode` is non-nullable.
If column `barcode` is nullable (and you are genuinely interested in records where `barcode IS NULL`), then the following query might work for you:

```
SELECT item FROM tempTable
WHERE ISNULL(barcode, '') LIKE ISNULL(@barcode, '') + '%'
```

However, this version has two disadvantages:

- It *may* perform much slower, because the query optimizer may not benefit from an index on column `barcode`.
- If `@barcode = ''`, then it will match not only the non-null barcodes, but also the records with `barcode IS NULL`; whether this is acceptable, is up to you.

One last simplification: you may want to reach consensus with the outside world that they should set `@barcode = ''` instead of `NULL` to retrieve all records. Then you could replace `ISNULL(@barcode, '')` by `@barcode`.

Answer (score 0):

IF @barcode is null

begin

SELECT   item  FROM tempTable

end

else
SELECT  item  FROM tempTable where tempTable.barcode LIKE @barcode+'%'

Answer (score 0):

Apart of ppeterka's solution (which will causes an Index/Table Scan) there are at least three other solutions. These solutions could use an `Index Seek` if `@barcode` isn't NULL and, also, if there is an index on `barcode` column:

Solution #2: The execution plan isn't cached and reused:

```
SELECT item 
FROM tempTable
WHERE @barcode IS NULL OR tempTable.barcode LIKE @barcode+'%'
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Solution #3: The execution plan is cached (it can be used if the num. of optional parameters is small):

```
IF @barcode IS NULL
    SELECT item 
    FROM tempTable;
ELSE
    SELECT item 
    FROM tempTable
    WHERE tempTable.barcode LIKE @barcode+'%';
```

Solution #4: The execution plans are cached (it can be used if the num. of optional parameters is high):

```
DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SqlStatement = N'
SELECT item 
FROM tempTable
WHERE 1=1 '
+ CASE WHEN @barcode IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N'AND tempTable.barcode LIKE @pBarcode+''%''; ' END; 
-- + CASE WHEN @anotherparam IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE 'AND ...' END ;

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement, N'@pBarcode VARCHAR(10)', @pBarcode = @barcode;
```

Note: Use the proper type and max. lenght/precision & scale for `@pBarcode` parameter.

Comment: Solution #3 & #4: the [estimated] execution plans are cached and reused.